# How can I make my datatable export the source data, not the generated data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-csv

Okay, so I have a datatable that I am trying to add the ability to export to a CSV. I can't seem to get it to export the actual value of the isAuthenticated/isDisabled columns though. The export is coming out with blank values for those columns, likely because I'm displaying an image in those columns using the columndefs rather than displaying the source data.

Am I generating the column values wrong or what direction should I go to export the actual true/false value for those columns?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dTable = $('#UserList').DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": false, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "pageLength": 10,
            "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp</div>',
            "buttons": [
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'Tool Users' }
                ],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Supervisor/UserData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "id", "width": "18%" },
                { "data": "fullName", "name": "fullName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "email", "name": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "isAuthenticated", "name": "isAuthenticated", "width":"8%" },
                { "data": "isDisabled", "name": "isDisabled", "width": "8%" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                    { return '<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" href="/Supervisor/EditUser/' + full.id + '">Edit</a> '; }
                }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return (data === true) ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-navy"></span>' : '<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>';
                    },
                    "targets": 3
                },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return (data === true) ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>' : '<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-navy"></span>';
                    },
                    "targets": 4
                }
            ],
            "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                if (aData.isAuthenticated) {

                }
                else {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" onclick=AuthenticateUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Authorize</a> ' ) ;
                }

                if (aData.isDisabled) {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" onclick=EnableUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Enable</a> ') ;

                }
                else {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-danger ManageUsersBtn" onclick=DisableUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Disable</a> ') ;
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up figuring it out. I had to specify different data depending on the return type, then set the orthogonal in export options. Its a bit messy but it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dTable = $('#UserList').DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": false, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "pageLength": 10,
            "dom": '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp</div>',
            "buttons": [
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'Tool Users', exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export', columns: [0,1,2,3,4] } }
                ],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Supervisor/UserData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "id", "width": "18%" },
                { "data": "fullName", "name": "fullName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "email", "name": "Email", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "isAuthenticated", "name": "isAuthenticated", "width":"8%" },
                { "data": "isDisabled", "name": "isDisabled", "width": "8%" },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                    { return '<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" href="/Supervisor/EditUser/' + full.id + '">Edit</a> '; }
                }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return type === 'export' ?
                            data == true ? "True" : "False" :
                            data === true ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-navy"></span>' : '<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>';

                    },
                    "targets": 3
                },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return type === 'export' ? 
                            data == true ? "True" : "False" : 
                            data == true ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>' : '<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-navy"></span>';
                    },
                    "targets": 4
                }
            ],
            "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                if (aData.isAuthenticated) {

                }
                else {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" onclick=AuthenticateUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Authorize</a> ' ) ;
                }

                if (aData.isDisabled) {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-info ManageUsersBtn" onclick=EnableUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Enable</a> ') ;

                }
                else {
                    $('td:eq(5)', nRow).append('<a class="btn btn-danger ManageUsersBtn" onclick=DisableUser("' + aData.id + '","' + aData.firstName + '","' + aData.lastName + '")>Disable</a> ') ;
                }
            },
        });
    });
```